# JQuery cloning of select areas and passing all to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I need to pass cloned areas of a form to PHP via post an add then each to an array.

My code

```
    <div class="input-main white_bg cloneneedsanalysis">
    <div class="action-input clone-needs-analysis">
    <div class="action-input-white-shorter">
    <div class="inner-sub-title-less-padding">
    <p>Audience Analysis</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." name="needs_analysis[]">
    <option value="">-- Choose Audience Categories --</option>
    <option value="536"> Finance -  - Cash collection </option>
    <option value="537"> IT -  - Comms IT </option>
    <option value="538"> Strategy -  - Strategy team 1 </option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action-input-plus-needs-analysis">  </div>
    <div class="action-input-remove-needs-analysis"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The cloning works, but when I send to PHP via POST it will only capture the last one because they are all called called needs_analysis[]

So, when cloning how can I edit the name so that it's different and how can I get PHP to loop though each of the arrays?

My JQuery;

```
$(document).on('click', '.clone_needs_analysis_button', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('.clone-needs-analysis').clone().insertAfter('.cloneneedsanalysis:last');
$(this).closest('.action-input-plus').hide();
$(this).closest('.action-input-remove').removeClass('hidden');
```

My PHP;

```
$needs_analysis = array();
foreach ($_POST['needs_analysis'] as $key => $value) {
    $needs_analysis[$key]['audience_id'] = $value;
    $needs_analysis[$key]['created'] = $_POST['updated'];
    $needs_analysis[$key]['created_by'] = $_POST['updated_by'];
    $needs_analysis[$key]['solution_id'] = $_POST['solution_id'];
}
foreach ($needs_analysis as $needs_analysis_insert) {
$db->insert('design_needs_analysis', $needs_analysis_insert);
}
```

Comment: where are your other inputs like updated created by ,audience?

Answer (score 0):

Your names for the multi-select should look like this:

```
needs_analysis[1][]
needs_analysis[2][]
```

You can either do this server-side, when generating the page, or rename them in `JavaScript`:

```
$('[name="needs_analysis[]"]').each(function(index) {
    var currentElement = $(this)
    currentElement.attr('name', 'needs_analysis['+index+'][]')
})
```

In order to loop through the values in `PHP`, you could do this:

```
foreach ($_POST['needs_analysis'] as $k=>$v) {
    //$v represents the value array for a select element
    foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2) {
        //do something with each value
    }
}
```